# parse xml files in root folder and its sub folders

Tags: python, parsing, elementtree

I'm working on a directory with 27 folders and various XML files inside each folder.

was able to:

- parse one XML file and write to a CSV file
- traverse one folder and read and parse all XML files in it

challenges:

- having a problem trying to go through and parse all the XML files from the root folder to its subfolders

Send help and thank you. Code snippets below

```
# working in one folder only
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

## directory
path = "/Users.../y"
filenames = []

## Count the number of xml files of each folder
files = os.listdir(path)
print("\n")


xml_data_to_csv = open('/Users.../xml_extract.csv', 'w')
list_head = []
csvwriter = csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)

# Read XML files in a folder
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'):
        continue
    fullname = os.path.join(path,filename)
    print("\n", fullname)
    filenames.append(fullname)

# parse elements in each XML file
for filename in filenames:
    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    root = tree.getroot()

    extract_xml=[]

    ## extract child elements per xml file
    print("\n")
    for x in root.iter('Info'):
        for element in x:
            print(element.tag,element.text)
            extract_xml.append(element.text)


    ## Write list nodes to csv
    csvwriter.writerow(extract_xml)

## Close CSV file
xml_data_to_csv.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of all the XML files in a given path with

```py
import os

path = "main/root"
filelist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if not file.endswith('.xml'):
            continue
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, file))

for file in filelist:
    print(file)
    # or in your case parse the XML 'file'
```

If for instance:

```
$ tree /main/root
/main/root
├── a
│   ├── a.xml
│   ├── b.xml
│   └── c.xml
├── b
│   ├── d.xml
│   ├── e.xml
│   └── x.txt
└── c
    ├── f.xml
    └── g.xml
```

we get:

```
/main/root/c/g.xml
/main/root/c/f.xml
/main/root/b/e.xml
/main/root/b/d.xml
/main/root/a/c.xml
/main/root/a/b.xml
/main/root/a/a.xml
```

If you want to sort directories and files:

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    dirs.sort()
    for file in sorted(files):
        if not file.endswith('.xml'):
            continue
        filelist.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: thanks for clearing this out. thank you all so much. in love with you guys already.

Comment: Also, is there a workflow or method to include a header or column name during parsing when saving it to csv?

Comment: You should create a new post for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
for dir_name, dirs, files in os.walk('<root_dir>'):
    # parse files
```

Comment: thank you all so much. in love with you guys already

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pathlib` module to "glob" the XML files. It will search all subdirectories for the pattern you supply and return `Path` objects that already include the path to the file. Cleaning up your script a bit, you would have

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from pathlib import Path

## directory
path = Path("/Users.../y")

with open('/Users.../xml_extract.csv', 'w') as xml_data_to_csv:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(xml_data_to_csv)

    # Read XML files in a folder
    for filepath in path.glob("**/*.xml"):
        tree = ET.parse(filename)
        root = tree.getroot()

        extract_xml=[]

        ## extract child elements per xml file
        print("\n")
        for x in root.iter('Info'):
            for element in x:
                print(element.tag,element.text)
                extract_xml.append(element.text)

        ## Write list nodes to csv
        csvwriter.writerow(extract_xml)
```

Comment: thank you all so much. in love with you guys already

Comment: suggestions or workaround as to how we can include header or column name to csv?

Comment: @Panda, right after creating `csvwriter`, you can write the header with `csvwriter.writerow(["column 1", "column 2", "column 3"])` ... replacing with your names of course.

Comment: tried this but it's giving me the column names on each row (like a loop)

Comment: @Panda What column names do you want? I can add it to the example.

Comment: Column names such as "file", "ext, "id", "user", "email"